# How to implement insert and sort method Comparable array with double link list in java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparable, insertion

I need help please, I tried to answer but it there a problem.

**My question is:**

Use the addAtFirstSmaller (T t) method to implement Insertion to sort a Comparable array a.

The implementation will be very simple with the method above.

1: Create a DoublyLinkedList list.call it a list.

2: Iterate over the array a. For each element t in a, add t to list by:
lista.addAtFirstSmaller (t);

3: Iterate over the list and place the respective elements in the corresponding place in a.
I have method addAtFirstSmaller (t).it work good.
I tried in the first tow steps, but I'm not understand how I implement step 3.

please I need help.

```
enter code here
 public Iterator<T> iterator() {

 return new Iterator<T>() {
    
         ListNode<T> node = head.next;

         @Override
         public boolean hasNext() {
          
                 return node != null;
         }

         @Override
         public T next() {
                 
                 if (!hasNext()) {
                         throw new NoSuchElementException();
                 }
                
                 T elem = node.element;
               
                 node = node.next;
             
                 return elem;
         }
         @Override
         public void remove() {
         }
     };
    }
public void addAtFirstSmaller(T t) {

ListNode<T> curr = getLast();

 or a node with value < t
while(curr != head)
{
    if(curr.element.compareTo(t) < 0) 
        break;
    curr = curr.pre;
}

if(curr == head) 
{
    addFirst(t);
}
else
{
  
    ListNode<T> node = new ListNode<T>(curr, curr.pre, t);
   
   
    curr.pre.next = node;
    curr.pre = node; 
}  
}


  enter code here
 public void insertionSort(Comparable[] a) {
    DoublyLinkedList<T> lista = new DoublyLinkedList<T>();

      T  t;
      int ind =0;
 
for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
     t =  (T) a[i]; 
    
    lista.addAtFirstSmaller(t);
    }
    
    Iterator<T> ite = lista.iterator();
    while(ite.hasNext()) {
     a[ind] = ite.next();
     ind++;
    }
  } 

  // TestClass
  public static void main(string[] args){
    Comparable[] a = new Comparable[5];
    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> lista = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
    a[0] = Integer.valueOf(13);
    a[1] = Integer.valueOf(2);
    a[2] = Integer.valueOf(1);
    a[3] = Integer.valueOf(5);
    a[4] = Integer.valueOf(8);
    System.out.println("The insertion sort för comprable a array is:");
    lista.insertionSort(a);
    System.out.println(lista);}
```

I hope help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating the elements that you get from the iterator and putting them back into the array `a` you need two variables: The `Iterator` that you get from `lista.iterator()` and an index into the array (an `int`). Initialize the index to 0. For each element that you get from the iterator put it into the array at the current index, then increment the index. In this way the elements will be stored into `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, etc.

Edit: Have your iterator control a loop for iterating. Personally I prefer a `while` lopp, there are some that prefer a `for` loop. You will find numerous examples on both in the Internet. Use your search engine.

Edit: This line in your iterator looks wrong:

```
     ListNode<T> node = head.next;
```

It seems to me that you are initializing `node` to refer to the *second* node of your list, thus skipping the first node.

Edit: You have got two variables named `lista`. There’s one in your `main` method. And there’s another one in the `insertionSort` method of `DoublyLinkedList`. When doing your insertion sort, you are filling the numbers into the latter. After the sort you are printing the former. So don’t expect to have your sorted list printed. However if I understood correctly, the end goal was to get your array sorted. So just print it:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

This should give you the end result.

Comment: I added this code   int ind = 0;                                                                             Iterator<T> ite = lista.iterator();a[ind] = (Comparable) ite;
                ind++; I get Exception that se "DoublyLinkedList$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Comment: Good start! Now you need a loop. I added a couple of sentences about it at the end of my answer.

Comment: du you mean while(ite.hasNext()){a[ind]= ite.next()}?

Comment: Yes, exactly! And then also increment `ind` inside the loop..

Comment: Look at my code now it still not work, I get empty list when I run test class

Comment: I get the first three element 13,2,1 and then []

Comment: Weird. Your code for filling the array looks just right, so the error is probably somewhere else. Maybe in your sorting, for example somewhere in `addAtFirstSmaller()`? Or maybe in your iterator implementation? Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: I added iterator and addAtFirstSmaller() metoder, I hope you kan help me, I do't know how to do debugging in Eclipse.

Comment: I think in iterator because I tested it I get this Exception "DoublyLinkedList$1@7852e922", do you know where is the problem?

Comment: That cannot be the full exception message? In any case I added a suggestion for an error in your iterator that may account for missing elements, but I don’t think that it would cause any exception except if the list was empty (`head` was `null`).

Comment: when I set  ListNode<T> node = head; I will get error Exception head is null for another methods

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I added a paragraph about which result you are printing.